# How to properly convert a message from RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I am trying to convert a message from Rabbit,so, I started to use a converter.

I have my listener like this

```
@Bean(name = "myMessageListener")
    @DependsOn("myQueue")
    MessageListener messageListener(@Qualifier("myMessageConverter") MessageConverter messageConverter) {
        return new myEventListener(messageConverter);
    }
```

So, at my listener class

```
public void onMessage(Message message){
    final MyClass myObject = (MyClass) messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
```

And here I get a cast error, cannot be converted.

MyClass is a 2 field object: ID and Name

I can succesfully convert it if I do the follow

```
byte[] body = message.getBody();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = new String(body)
MyClass myObject = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, MyClass.class);
```

But of course, doesnt seem to be a nice solution.

Is there any more elegant/eloquent solution to fix this?

Thanks.